# Is there a word for languages "equivalent to C"?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm trying to find a word to categorize some languages, and don't quite have it.

- Category 1 Example: A Ruby program must be interpreted; it is really instructions for the `ruby` program. Python and Javascript are like this, too.
- Category 2 Example: A compiled C program needs no interpreter; it is really instructions for the computer. C++ , Rust and Go are like this, too.

I would say "compiled vs interpreted", but there are languages that compile to bytecode. Eg, Java compiles, but you can't run a Java program without having Java installed.

I would say "compiles to machine code", but I've read that C compilers may compile to assembler instead, and I'm fuzzy on that distinction anyway. Which raises the question "are we even talking about a feature of the language itself?" You can write [a C interpreter](https://code.google.com/p/picoc/), after all.

Informally, I'd say "you can use Rust or Go to do the kinds of things you'd use C for - to produce efficient binaries with no runtime dependencies."

Is there a word for "equivalent to C" in this sense?

Answer (score 1):

No.

As you've already alluded to, there are various ways of classifying a language.

- How it is executed (compiled vs interpreted)
- How it exists at the lowest level (byte code vs machine code)
- Similarity of the language syntax
- Problem domain (scripting language, general purpose, functional programming)

Even the first of these falls down with C. It is perfectly possible to write a C interpreter - see **Herbert Schildt's C : The complete reference** for such an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want really categorize languages you should pass through metaprogramming and programming paradigms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) and metalanguage
because even if a language is mainly compiled and another is mainly interpreted, it's the compiler/intepreter which decides to pass through bytecodes/opcodes or to compile in machine language, to incrementally compile or to interactively compile and so on..

I hope to be helpful.